# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch when I launch the bot in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm developing a bot, the package.json file is this:

```
{
  "name": "mybot-heroku",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An in-depth guide on deploying your Discord.js bot on Heroku",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.x",
    "npm": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "worker":  "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.3.0"
  }
}
```

And the index.js file is this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot ready!`)
})

client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.author.bot === false){
    author=msg.author
    date = new Date()
    msg1 = msg.content
    msg2 = msg1.toLowerCase()
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[àáâãäå]/g),"a")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[èéêë]/g),"e")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[ìíîï]/g),"i")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[òóôõö]/g),"o")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[ùúûü]/g),"u")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[ýÿ]/g),"y")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/ç/g),"c")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("año",date.getFullYear())
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/ñ/g),"n")
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[¿?¡!;:,]/g),"")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("y","+")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("mas","+")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("menos","-")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("por","*")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("entre","/")
    msg2 = msg2.replace("mes",date.getMonth())
    msg2 = msg2.replace("dia",date.getDate())
    msg2 = msg2.replace("hora",date.getHours())
    msg2 = msg2.replace("minutos",date.getMinutes())
    msg2 = msg2.replace("segundos",date.getSeconds())
    msg2 = msg2.replace(new RegExp(/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]/g),"")
    insultos=[
      "put",
      "cabron",
      "maric",
      "jod",
      "poll",
      "retrasad",
      "gut",
      "noob",
      "whore",
      "bitch",
      "suck",
      "retard",
      "dumb",
      "idiot",
      "gay",
      "lamb",
      "borrego",
      "huev",
      "perolo",
      "chot",
      "tranc",
      "pij",
      "verg",
      "pendej"
    ]
    contiene_insultos_var=false
    for(i in insultos){
      if(msg1.includes(insultos[i])){
        contiene_insultos_var=true
      }
    }
    if(contiene_insultos_var==true){
      msg.reply("Tu mensaje contiene insultos.")
    }else{
      msg.reply("Tu mensaje no contiene insultos.")
    }
  }
})
```

And... after I launch, it keeps running, but after 5 minutes, the bot crashes giving this error:

```
2020-11-27T20:17:20.226333+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-11-27T20:17:20.250892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-11-27T20:17:20.317446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-11-27T20:17:20.354218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

What could I do for avoid this error? The error is giving when I relaunch the bot, I know that the error is because the conexion has been interrupted, but I have no information or idea. Any help? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, you must change from **web** to **worker**

Run this command using heroku CLI:

```
heroku scale web=0 worker=1 -a <APP_NAME>

OR

heroku scale worker=1 -a <APP_NAME>
```

And change your `Procfile` from **web** to **worker** too

before (example):

```
web: npm start
```

after (example):

```
worker: npm start
```

Obs: May the bot don't instantly start, and in this case, you will have to go to `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<APP-NAME>/resources` and enable the worker